# check collection existence - Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Example:

I have to make an appointment with the Firestore before proceeding with the event scheduling function.

```
Example in the database:
- Companie1 (Document)
--- name
--- phone
--- Schedules (Collection)
-----Event 1
-----Event 2
```

I have a function that performs a new schedule.

According to the example.
I need to check if the Schedules collection exists.

If it does not exist I execute the scheduling function. If I already exist I need to do another procedure.

I already used this pattern and not right.

```
db.collection("Companies").document(IDCOMPANIE1)
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

I need help finding a way to do this before proceeding with the registration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The achieve this just check for nullity:

```
DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
if (document != null) {
    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + task.getResult().getData());
    //Do the registration
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
}
```

The result of this `Task` is a `DocumentSnapshot`. Whether or not the underlying document actually exists is available via the [exists()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#exists()) method.

If the document does exist you can call getData to get at the contents of it.

```
db.collection("Companies").document(IDCOMPANIE1)
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    if(document.exists()) {
                        //Do something
                    } else {
                        //Do something else
                    }

                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

If you want know if the `task` is empty, please use the following line of code:

```
boolean isEmpty = task.getResult().isEmpty();
```

Comment: I need to check if the collection Schedules exists.So I just check if it has any data? @AlexMamo

Comment: Yes, just see if ti's null. If is not, means that contains informations.

Comment: Yes, but you'll always have the information. Except collection Schedules.This one may or may not. I would need to check if it exists, only. @AlexMamo

Comment: Even with getData I could not check if the collection exists. @AlexMamo

Comment: You don't need to use getData(). Please see my updated answer.

Comment: In my example above. According to your help I would get the information: name, phone. The Schedules is Collection, not Document. How do I check if it exists? @AlexMamo

Comment: I understood. But what guarantee does the collection (Schedules) exist? @AlexMamo

Comment: I don't understand your question entirely but i can say that the guarantee is from Firebase creators which have created this method to help us verify if a collection does really exist.