# Kotlin Firestore - Fetching Fields from Specific Document

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have multiple collections which store various documents, and I'm attempting to reach a specific collection so that I may retrieve fields from a specific document. I am attempting to do this in `onStart`

```
John Doe ----> "DocumentId (a23bsz12bvxaQw2)" ----> |name: John Doe, age: 23, occupation: teacher|
```

I am able to retrieve the specific collection in another method, however that's only because I'm able to pass in the name of the collection as a parameter. The only way for me to reach a specific Collection is by hard-coding the `fieldPath`.

This is my code thus far:

```
 override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    val caseManagerNameOnStart = caseManagerName?.text

    val notebookRef = db.collection("$caseManagerNameOnStart")
    notebookRef.addSnapshotListener(this, object : EventListener<QuerySnapshot?> {
        override fun onEvent(querySnap: QuerySnapshot?, ex: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
            if (ex != null) {
                return
            }
            if (querySnap != null) {
                for (documentSnapshot in querySnap) {
                    val appointment = documentSnapshot.toObject(
                        Appointment::class.java
                    )
                    appointment.setId(documentSnapshot.id)
                    appointment_text_view_date.text =
                        "Date: " + documentSnapshot["dateAppointment"].toString()
                    appointment_text_view_time.text =
                        "Time: " + documentSnapshot["timeAppointment"].toString()
                    appointment_text_view_case_manager.text =
                        "Case Manager: " + documentSnapshot["caseManagerName"].toString()
                    appointment_text_view_client_name.text =
                        "Client: " + documentSnapshot["userName"].toString()
                    appointment_text_view_format.text =
                        "Format: " + documentSnapshot["formatAppointment"].toString()
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

`val caseManagerNameOnStart = caseManagerName?.text` seems to be empty, and the app crashes when I call the activity in question. `caseManagerName` should hold the name which can be used in for `fieldPath`, however there is a case where there might not be a collection to retrieve, and thus nothing should be set to the TextViews.

My expected output is this:

1. Get specified collection
2. Retrieve fields from document
3. Display these fields in given TextViews
4. If no collection is available, prevent `onStart` from crashing app.

Here is an image of my data in Firestore.
[Firestore Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQQlc.png)

I would highly appreciate any input. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Which type of object is `caseManagerName`?

Comment: It is a String derived from an EditText.

Comment: Hey from where are you getting this `caseManagerName?.text` ? As you said you are getting `caseManagerNameOnStart` as empty that's the only reason  your app crashes as you are passing null values in `db.collection("$caseManagerNameOnStart")`. Although please make sure that there is something in that edit text field or else you'll keep passing nil values and your app will crash

Comment: You can set some _not empty_ flow control to this field calling `if (caseManagerNameOnStart.isEmpty()) return` or logging some warning

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please add a screenshot of it.

Comment: @AppDev. I know I have the values are stored in Firestore, however, I don't believe the values are stored locally. caseManagerName is stored unto Firestore when the user inputs the proper fields. Furthermore, the same value for caseManagerName is stored in a Firebase Database, but I wasn't able to retrieve the value, and pass it into db.collection().

Comment: To move things along, a screenshot of your data would help.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thank you for your response. I've gone ahead, and provided a screenshot of the data. I apologize for the delay! I've been in the process of moving apartments.

Comment: @MrTech Thank you for your response! Please check the post again, as I've provided a screenshot of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> however that's only because I'm able to pass in the name of the collection as a parameter.

It is mandatory to know the name of the collection, in order to access the properties of the documents.

> val caseManagerNameOnStart = caseManagerName?.text seems to be empty, and the app crashes

It is empty, the reason why you have that crash.

> caseManagerName should hold the name which can be used in for fieldPath

Or you can save the name of the collection in another type of object, for example, in SharedPreferences.

> however there is a case where there might not be a collection to retrieve, and thus nothing should be set to the TextViews.

This is how you can check a collection for existence, before setting something in the reference.

- [check collection existence - Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244134/check-collection-existence-firestore)

Comment: Thank you so much! Utilizing SharedPreferences helped me solve this issue!